# NSwag for Asp.Net Web Api 2 show security in swagger gui

Tags: authentication, swagger, nswag

We have installed nswag in our project and it works fine so far.

But all our functions are secured with an api-key.

when I take a look on the demo page from swagger, I can see the lock a the end of each api call where I need to Authorize (I think thats the lock for)

https://petstore.swagger.io/#/

[image]

In our local installation we got the "Authorize" Button and we can set the Key but I don't know how to activate the lock sign in api calls? Is there an Attribute I need to set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution was to set the GeneratorSettings.OperationProcessors for the ApiKey only with this option it was working. in my global.asax in Application_Start.

```
  app.UseSwaggerUi3(typeof(WebApiApplication).Assembly, settings =>
            {

                settings.MiddlewareBasePath = "/swagger";
                settings.GeneratorSettings.DocumentProcessors.Add(new SecurityDefinitionAppender("ApiKey", new SwaggerSecurityScheme
                {
                    Type = SwaggerSecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
                    Name = "X-API-KEY",
                    In = SwaggerSecurityApiKeyLocation.Header
                }));
                settings.GeneratorSettings.OperationProcessors.Add(new OperationSecurityScopeProcessor("ApiKey"));
            });
```

Comment: This will be silently ignored with AddOpenAPIDocument (swagger v3+)

Answer (score 2):

Generator settings have been deprecated and this will silently fail when you use AddOpenAPIDocument (Swagger V3+ / OpenAPI).

Instead, you need to add similar settings to the document.
https://github.com/RSuter/NSwag/wiki/AspNetCore-Middleware#enable-api-key-authorization

```
services.AddOpenApiDocument(document => 
{
    document.DocumentProcessors.Add(
        new SecurityDefinitionAppender("apikey", new SwaggerSecurityScheme
        {
            Type = SwaggerSecuritySchemeType.ApiKey,
            Name = "api_key",
            In = SwaggerSecurityApiKeyLocation.Header
        })
    );
});
```

Comment: I am facing the same problem. What is the solution for NSwag in WebApi 2 *not* Asp.Net Core?